# What can the Fire Prevention Specialist do in Flash Point: Fire Rescue?

Tags: flash-point

The Fire Prevention Specialist comes exclusively with the Kickstarter version of the Honor and Duty expansion for Flash Point: Fire Rescue. No additional rules for his character came with the expansion. On his card, his actions are:

Prevent: 1 AP
Move Smoke

Prevent: 2 AP
Movie POI

So, from what I understand, he CAN spray out fire, rescue, and chop like most of the other specialists, but what are the exact conditions of the two "prevent" actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for this Kickstarter-exclusive role were provided via [this update](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2012515236/flash-point-call-of-duty-expansion/posts/1093954).

> *This is a tribute to the unsung heroes– the men and women in the administrative branch of the fire service. They evaluate fires, propose regulations and see to it that they are observed. They work with files and records instead of hoses and axes, and their work saves many lives.*
>
> **The Fire Prevention Specialist - 4AP**
>
> This specialist has done his work years ago; he talked to the builders and home owners and convinced them to adopt a fire security plan. On his advice smoke detectors and smoke exhausts have been installed, and emergency exits have been planned and marked clearly. Now these measures prove their worth: People are warned and can move out via marked escape routes, and smoke clears itself from the building.
>
> **Prevent/De-Smoke: Move a smoke** token anywhere on the board for 1 AP per space. Movement must be on the shortest route towards nearest exterior door, playerʼs choice if alternative routes exist; Smoke passes closed interior doors at no extra cost. Smoke vanishes when outside the building. Moved smoke ignites immediately if adjacent to fire; if it moves on top of other smoke, it becomes fire.
>
> **Prevent/Escape: Move a POI token** (only if "?" side up) anywhere on the board for 2 AP per space. Movement must be on the shortest route towards nearest exterior door, playerʼs choice if alternative routes exist. POIs can open doors on their way for 2 AP; they will not use breached walls, ladders etc. (they use the escape route "as marked"). POIs moved outside of the building (=coordinate area) are revealed. POIs will not move into fire.
>
> Note: If playing with multi-floor game boards, "shortest route to exterior door" may be via a stair way.
>
> Note: In the subway station, exits are all spaces with an ambulance symbol.
>
> Note: De-Smoke and Escape are always determined by the nearest exterior doors – not opened windows, nor destroyed walls

---

The flavour text of the Fire Prevention Specialist suggest they are not found at the scene of a fire (in an active role).

I would certainly encourage players to restrict themselves to the two actions described above, but there's no rules to suggest they should be limited to those two actions.

If you wish to participate in the field, you could say that the fire department is short-handed, so their FPS also serves as a regular fireman.

Comment: "They work with files and records instead of hoses and axes, and their work saves many lives." - Does this mean he CAN'T spray and chop?

Comment: Could you please post a link to where BGG agrees? Always good to cite your sources ;-)